# AVCaptureDevice Unsupported frame duration iPhone 11 Pro Max

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I have been using `AVCaptureDevice` method set `activeVideoMinFrameDuration`  prior to the new **iPhone 11** without any problems however testing the same code with the new **iPhone 11 Pro max** (Actual device), The app crashes with error message: -

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:-[AVCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:] Unsupported frame duration - use -activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges to discover valid ranges**

The same code works well with older phones. Actually I am using the exact sample code from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice)

```
func configureCameraForHighestFrameRate(device: AVCaptureDevice) {

    var bestFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format?
    var bestFrameRateRange: AVFrameRateRange?

    for format in device.formats {
        for range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges {
            if range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange?.maxFrameRate ?? 0 {
                bestFormat = format
                bestFrameRateRange = range
            }
        }
    }

    if let bestFormat = bestFormat, 
       let bestFrameRateRange = bestFrameRateRange {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            // Set the device's active format.
            device.activeFormat = bestFormat

            // Set the device's min/max frame duration.
            let duration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration
            device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = duration
            device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = duration

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            // Handle error.
        }
    }
}
```

As I have mentioned above this code works well with older devices but not iPhone 11 series (Tested on 11 Pro max).

Does anyone have a workaround or solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you working around something preferredVideoStabilizationMode ?

Comment: @BandishDave  back then I was working on live broadcasting app and I was able to resolve the issue as described on accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who will run into the same issue in the future. Here is what I did to fix the issue by following the debug error description.

```
 // Important part: You must get the supported frame duration and use it to set max and min frame durations. 
let supporrtedFrameRanges = device.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.first

// Then use it, note that only fall back to bestFrameRateRange if supporrtedFrameRanges is nil.            
device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = supporrtedFrameRanges?.minFrameDuration ?? bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration
device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = supporrtedFrameRanges?.maxFrameDuration ?? bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameDuration
```

Comment: I am stuck in task of video stabilisation either pre or post video recording.... can you please help me if you can.

Comment: Hi, @BandishDave I think you have to post a brand new question about your issue, taht way you can get more people to help. Be sure to post detailed information including your attempt to the problem.